# Windows 8 login screen doesn't have username saved

Tags: windows-8, login, authentication

My login screen is different from what I see from other Windows 8 and does not have my username/profile picture automatically saved. [Here](http://michaelsync.net/2011/09/14/finally-windows-8-is-on-vm.) is an example I found online (first green image on the page (5th jpg)

[image]

Instead, what is shown on the regular login screen are two icons both of which are gray squares with a "key" inside as the image. When I click on the key icon on the left, it asks to input a Username and a Password.  The key icon on the right asks for an Email and Password. Why is there both? How come my username is not automatically saved so all I have to do is put in a password?

I'm assuming what I should see on the screen are two icons: one with my name synced to it as well as the profile picture (requiring only the password) and the other one for guest. Am I wrong?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Vivian, when you have your own problem you should open a new question. Answers are for answers to the current question.

Comment: "My situation is a little different" - is this a continuation of someone elses question or something? Also, I don't really understand the problem. Can you provide more info on your computer setup? Is it a corporate computer or a home one?

Comment: Sorry Isaac, I thought I posted a new question. How can I tell from this? The "my situation is a little different" was mentioned because I couldn't find my solution on the website. @Sam: this is a home computer, Lenovo U310 with Windows 8. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does. Lenovo installs a lot of bloatware. I've just ordered a Lenovo laptop and the first thing I will do when I get it is format it. Also, I could tell from this "my situation is a little different" because it just seemed like a continuation of another question. It's the wording.

Comment: Sorry about the wording. @Sam, do you know the solution to my problem? Or should I post another question for clarity sake?

Comment: Hi. I can't really understand the question. Just edit the one you have here so it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems Cisco AnyConnect caused this. I uninstalled the program and the problem was gone. I have read that this occurs with many other VPN clients.